# Будет ли метод помеченный аннотацией @Asyncronus выполняться асинхронно, если в нем вызываются методы не помеченные, как асинхронные?

Tags: java, android-asynctask, ejb

Будет ли метод помеченный аннотацией @Asyncronus выполняться асинхронно, если в нем вызываются методы не помеченные, как асинхронные ?

Comment: Сформулируйте что для вас значит "асинхронны метод"

Comment: Вопрос возник когда было решено отрефакторить метод с низкой производительностью. Метод(помечен аннотацией) был вынесен в бин, но он вызывал цепочку методов не помеченных @Asyncronus, дебаг показал. Тесты показали, что прироста в скорости нет. Дебаг показал, что метод выполняется в разных потоках, но синхронно. А асинхронность для меня - это выполнение некоторых полезных действий в других потоках с ожиданием коллбека в главном.

Comment: Если быть точнее то код из которого был запущен асинхронный метод не дожидается окончания выполнения этого метода а сразу переходит к выполнению следующнго действия.  Код который помечен как асинхронный выполняется отдельным потоком и не создаёт цепочки асинхронных потоков для каждого метода увидеть как это работает можно с помощью http://http://www.jconcurrent.com.

Comment: Ну а если говорить об оптимизации то всегда нужно смотреть не на потоки на алгоритмы которые были использованы и архитектуру в целом. Если есть код то пожалуйста добавьте его и если есть возможность его оптимизировать то вам помогут.

Comment: Тот участок уже отрефакторили и уперлись в производительность entityManager(хотя и переписали все на netive sql).